# Selenium IDE How to set timeout?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE and when trying to use `wait for element present` command, i got this error:

[image]

But i couldn't find anywhere to set the timeout at all, i'm using the Chrome extension

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out after looking at `Reference` tab.

[image]

It is set using `Value` field.

[image]

Comment: In my case It looks like is not taking the timeout from this field

Comment: It seems like max value is 30000